# Combining Columnizer and JQuery's Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have content:

```
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
```

I'm using the [columnizer plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) which separates my content into two columns like this:

```
<div class="first column" style="width:50%; float: left;">
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<div class="last column" style="width:50%; float: left;">
  <div>content</div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

I'd also like to use [JQuery's Sortable function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to make my content sortable. This requires that I add a UL wrapper and LI's around each content section. However, the columnizer plugin breaks my sortable UL into two UL's (with identical IDs...) allowing only the first column to be sortable:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
  <div class="first column" style="width:50%; float: left;">
    <li><div>content</div></li>
    <li><div>content</div></li>
    <li><div>content</div></li>
  </div>
</ul>                   //inserted by columnizer
<ul id='sortable'>      //inserted by columnizer
  <div class="last column" style="width:50%; float: left;">
    <li><div>content</div></li>
    <li><div>content</div></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

- Can I configure "columnizer" to not do this?
- If not, is there a better (and supported) way to make columns without it?
- **I'd like to avoid using the "grid" layout** offered by JQuery since my content has varying heights and grids would introduce a lot of whitespace.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I've made progress on my own. Instead of referencing the ul ID for sortable, I referenced a common CLASS between the UL's that columnizer creates and connected them:

    <ul class='ul_sortable'>...

And then my JQuery: 

    $(".ul_sortable").sortable({connectWith: '.ul_sortable'});

Sorting within a single column or from right-to-left works flawlessly, but dragging from the left-column to the right-column is hit-or-miss. Perhaps I NEED to use ID's instead of classes?

Comment: SOLVED: it turns out sortable DOES NOT require using ul's and li's. I ran "sortable" on my container div, and set sortable's "item" option to a common class between all my content divs. Works flawlessly now. ...and stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question, and so my solution goes here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out sortable DOES NOT require using `<ul>` and `<li>`. I ran `sortable()` on my container div, and set sortable's `item` option to a common class between all my content divs.